# Website for audio equipment specifications?

Tags: audio, speakers, tech-specs

I'm looking for a website where I can compare audio equipment just by specification listings. A lot of times, I notice that several specifications are either incomplete or meaningless (looking at you, frequency response).

I always thought that if the vendor's website itself doesn't list all the specs, then the specs simply don't exist. However, when I was looking at PC display monitors, there's [a website called Hardware.Info](http://us.hardware.info/comparisontable/products/327886) which somehow gets specifications that even the vendor's website doesn't have (possibly from the manuals that come with the products). Additionally, it lets you easily compare different monitors.

Therefore, I was wondering if some such similar website existed for audio equipment.

Comment: Not that I know of. It could be due to the wide variety (analog vs. digital, home vs. studio) of options. Even if you had software (robots) to scan websites using certain search terms such as 'noise floor', many websites will kick out robot scanners or block them. This sounds like a DIY job.